# How to optimize SQLite indexes for query

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table as

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    CategoryCode NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    DateTime     DateTime NOT NULL,
    ItemCode     NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    ItemName     NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    ItemValue    NUMERIC(28, 4) NOT NULL
)
```

The question is how to optimize indexes for the following query:

```
SELECT
 CategoryCode
,ItemCode
,ItemName
,SUM(ItemValue) as TotalValue
FROM T
WHERE CategoryCode = 'Code1' 
AND DateTime < '2012-01-04 00:00:00'
GROUP BY ItemCode
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the exact query, you will need an index on `T(CategoryCode, DateTime)` or `T(DateTime, CategoryCode)`, depending on which column is more selective than the other.

However, it is unwise to create an index for a single query without a more holistic view on all access to the table.

e.g. You may find, for example, that if most data in the table has `CategoryCode = 'Code1'` then the index should only be created on the `DateTime` column.

Comment: Unless something has changed in recent versions of sqlite, the query plan would check `CategoryCode` first.  If you didn't include it in the index, I believe you'd be looking at a table scan.